# enumitem and paragraph spacing: blank line between for parskip, no line between for regular line break

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, enumitem, parskip

I would essentially like to have two spacings between lists and paragraphs, for two separate purposes. If the list is in the middle of a paragraph, use the regular line spacing. If the list is the last part of a paragraph, use regular line spacing before the list, and paragraph spacing after the list. I would like to achieve this behaviour by using a blank line, as I would for normal paragraph typing. Please see the MWE below, it describes what I want to achieve.

P.S. if this is bad typographical practice, please critique, but offer justification and recommended practice :)

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{scrhack}% is this required with enumitem?

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=-\parskip}


\begin{document}

\section{List embedded in paragraph}
A paragraph to demonstrate full parskip.

Here is a paragraph.
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is an item; and%
    \item this is another one.
\end{itemize}
I want to continue the pararaph, and therefore have no spacing between this line and the one above.

\section{List ending a paragraph}

\subsection{The syntax I want, but the result I do not}
Here is another paragraph.
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is an item; and
    \item this is another one, ending the paragraph.
\end{itemize}

I want to start a new paragraph, and write it in LaTeX by specifying the blank line (above), as I would for separating bodies of text.

\subsection{The result I want, but hacky syntax}
Here is another paragraph.
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is an item; and
    \item this is another one, ending the paragraph.
\end{itemize}

\vspace{\parskip}
Unfortunately I have to use vspace. Is it possible to automatically detect the blank line so I don't have to use vspace?

Bonus: is it possible to achieve this result for a blank line above a list? i.e. if there is a blank line, use paragraph spacing before the list?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: (a less hacky way, but not automatic detection) [Modifying whitespace before and after list separately using enumitem package](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/199118)

Comment: Thanks; seeing as I'll more likely end a paragraph with a list, this will serve as a good alternative for now.